# ListboxItem self binding

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

How can i bind a command parameter to self?

I try like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Button Content="G"
                       Background="Green"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                 Path=DataContext.LabelGoodCommand}"       
                       CommandParameter="{Binding /}"
                       Width="20" Height="20" />
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But this doesn't work.
In viewmodel listbox items binding to ObservableCollection.

Comment: What do you mean by "self"? The button itself?

Comment: No, i know how to get a button, i need a model associated with item

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If by "self", you mean the button, you can do that:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
```

If you want the current `DataContext`, just don't specify the path:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Comment: By this way i get a button instead of model. I need a model in parameter

Comment: LOL, i try {Binding /}, but answer just was {Binding}.

Answer (score 0):

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
```

By this you can get the Control and in your Execute method, Use as like this,

```
if(pram is Button)
{
    var model = ((Button)pram).DataContext;
}
```

you can get the Model here.

**OR**

```
           <Button Content="G"
                   Background="Green"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                             Path=DataContext.LabelGoodCommand}"       
                   CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"
                   Width="20" Height="20" />
```

**OR**

```
<Button Content="G"
                   Background="Green"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                             Path=DataContext.LabelGoodCommand}"       
                   CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
                   Width="20" Height="20" />
```

Comment: Looks like a hack. There is the normal way?Thank you